# AttributeError: _member_count

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
Exception has occured: AttributeError
_member_count
```

in on_guild_remove

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    channel = client.get_channel(ID)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=guild.name, description=f'Member Count: {guild.member_count}', colour = discord.Color.red())
    embed.set_author(name='Removed', icon_url=guild.icon_url_as())
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=guild.icon_url)
    embed.add_field(name='Owner', value=guild.owner_id, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Owner', value=guild.region, inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

There seems to be no problem when i have this exact code in on_guild_join.

Answer (score -1):

Change `guild.member_count` to `len(guild.members)`

`AttributeError _member_count` means that the object `guild` does not have an attribute called `member_count`

Comment: Changed and there is an error: object MemberIterator can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: Try changing it to my updated answer, basically `len(guild.members)`

Comment: That did work but as soon as i run the file it sends the message and doesnt wait for "on_guild_remove"

Comment: Can you edit your question and show all the code because currently I am only seeing the embed and nothing more

Comment: Try doing `return await channel.send(embed=embed)` but I don't really see why it gets sent as soon as you run the file, are you sure it is from the `on_guild_remove` function?

Comment: It still sends the message. and yes it is from the `on_guild_remove`

Comment: That doesn't make sense, if this function is never invoked then it will never execute that message.

Comment: It also says: `line 717, in member_count` `return self._member_count` < This in file guild.py